# cannot find FirstFragmentDirections & SecondFragmentArgs

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**From:** https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/build-your-first-android-app/#8

**AndroidStudio 3.6.2**

**Last tasks in the step-by-step guide are producing the following errors:**

> cannot find a symbol variable SecondFragmentArgs
>   package FirstFragmentDirections does not exist
>   cannot find symbol variable FirstFragmentDirections

**Here is a sample of the code from SecondFragment.java:**

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {
    Integer myArg = SecondFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments()).getMyArg();
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
    }
```

**Here is the code from FirstFragment.java:**

```
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    view.findViewById(R.id.random_button);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TextView showCountTextView = view.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.textview_first);
            int currentCount = Integer.parseInt(showCountTextView.getText().toString());
            FirstFragmentDirections.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment action = FirstFragmentDirections.actionFirstFragmentToSecondFragment(currentCount);
            NavHostFragment.findNavController(FirstFragment.this).navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment);
        }
    });

    view.findViewById(R.id.toast_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hello toast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            myToast.show();
        }
    });

    view.findViewById(R.id.count_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            countMe(view);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: show the navigation xml file

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue, it turned out the codelab was referencing an alpha version of SafeArgs in the `Build.gradle` file. To fix it, just include the latest classpath in your top level `Build.gradle` file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        def nav_version = "2.3.0"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
    }
}
```

Also, do not forget to apply plugin to your **app or module's** `Build.gradle` file:

`apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"` if using Java or

`apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"` for Kotlin

EDIT: For the sake of completeness, you also need to Rebuild Gradle for the FirstFragmentDirections generated class to be added. That can be done by choosing Build > Make Project in the tool menu.

Consult with the official docs below, as they offer additional troubleshooting if the above is not working.
Referenced Docs

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#safe_args

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26711442)

Comment: @samabcde I've tried to edit it so its clearer, thanks!

Comment: It's been a while, but I'd like to add that I faced the same issue, but the thing was that I copied and pasted project files (such as build.gradle) from one of my computers to another. All I needed to do is edit the build.gradle file by removing and putting back a single character so I could do a project sync, and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Project Structure -> Gradle Version` needs to be at least 6.1.1.
2. Open your Gradle sidebar on the far right (or double shift -> Gradle).
3. Click the "Toggle Offline Mode" so it's off.
4. This could start a massive Gradle download, wait until finished.
5. Go to `Build -> Make`
6. Don't forget to sync.